# Position text on the bottom of background picture when scaling

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve a function similar to [this](https://cloud.google.com/why-google-cloud/).

If you start to scale the window down, you can see that the text saying "Engineered to help business thrive" goes to the bottom of the background image.

**CSS:**

```
#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #1C242B;
  border-bottom: #45A29E 3px solid;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section id="showcase">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There more than one way to do that by change the `position: absolute;` to  `position: relative` in media query.

check this https://jsfiddle.net/m0fushg6/3/

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
}

#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/5760/3840?image=1067') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #1C242B;
  border-bottom: #45A29E 3px solid;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(15%, -50%);
  color: #000;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 5%;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <div id="showcase"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome! this is exactly what I was looking for. Will be tweaking your code a bit but overall this will get me started!

Comment: Yeah exactly! I didn't know what else to add there, but i'm sure this will give you an idea how to work it

Answer (score 1):

Consider using media queries.

**Documentation:** https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

**Example:** https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_mediaqueries_ex1

**HTML**

```
<section id="showcase">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="outter-container">
  <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  background:url(https://kbob.github.io/images/sample-1.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #1C242B;
  border-bottom: #45A29E 3px solid;
}

.inner-container {
  display: inline;
}

.outter-container {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .inner-container {
    display: none;
  }

  .outter-container {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/qckv1cua/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try using media queries.

Examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```
<section id="showcase">
  <div class="container"> </div>
  <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#showcase {
 position:relative;
 min-height: 400px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #1C242B;
 border-bottom: #45A29E 3px solid;
}

.container{
/*Put your image in the container**/
  background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
/*set postion to absolute*/
  position:absolute;
/*set size of container*/
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
/*image fallback*/
  background:blue;
}

h1{
/*set postion to absolute and width to 100%*/
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
/*To get the text centered*/
}

/*Add a media query to catch when the window is 900px*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {

/*set both container and h1 element to static*/
 .container, h1{
  position:static; 
 }

}
```

This is how I would approach your problem.